# Custom bean with @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have method:

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityManager.check(#uuid)")
@GetMapping(path = URL_SUBMISSION_ID)
@ControllerLogging
public Object showSomething(@PathVariable(value = "submissionId") UUID submissionId) {
    return getData();
}
```

It works without problem, but I can't test it, because get error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression
>   '@securityManager.check(#uuid)'

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class MyTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                    .standaloneSetup(myController)
                    .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                    .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
          // Here some code with mvc mock
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        MyController myController() {
            return new MyController();
        }
    }
}
```

What do I miss?

Comment: There is no parameter `uuid` in the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with specifying stating "uuid" in the PreAuthorize method.
It should be rewritten to

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityManager.check(#submissionId)")
```